# Node.js suddenly can't find any modules anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was in my user folder (windows 10) and saw that there was a folder named node_modules and it had a few modules in it. I didn't want it in that directory, and went to look for the other modules which was located in the nodejs install directory. So I just cut and pasted it to the node_modules folder there. And now, node.js can't find the modules.
How do I fix this? Reinstalling the modules didn't work

This is my node_modules folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g2hQ.png
Everything is there, but when I run the script it doesn't find it https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ryeM.png
And it was working fine yesterday...

Answer (score 3):

delete the node_modules folder and just install all dependencies with `npm i`.

Comment: I renamed the node_modules folder instead of deleting it. When I win+R and start CMD, I type in `npm i` and get this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'`

Comment: if you run `npm -v` do you get a version number? use powershell instead of cmd. if nothing comes back you need to reinstall npm.

Comment: ok I reinstalled node.js and `npm -v` gives me 6.9.0. If I rename the folder node_modules and try `npm -v` again it gives me the same error as above. Dunno why you guys tell me to delete neccessary program files, that's not helping.

Comment: I added two screenshots to the initial post